# Dynamic content is not displayed on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After my page is loaded, I run a script where I dynamically add click event to my hidden button, and trigger the click. This way I am forcing a javascript library to reload every time a reload a page.
Then this library makes request, and response is being displayed in appropriate manner. 
First time I load the page, the response is displayed (selected text is highlighted). Every next time, library is reloaded, but response is not displayed. I want to make it displayed every time I reload the page.

I have tried to disable cache, refresh it with shift+f5, but still no success.

This is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="pdfContainer" class = "pdf-content">
        </div>
    </div>      
    <input id="btn" type="button" hidden="true" />

    <script>
        function loadAnnotator() {

            var content = $('#content').annotator();
            console.log("Annotator loaded");

        };
        $(window).load(function () {

            var btn = $("#btn");             
            if(btn !== null && btn !== undefined) {

                btn.on('click', loadAnnotator);                    
                btn.click();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I can make it work with displaying and manually clicking this button, but that is not the desired behavior.

How can I make it work the way I desire? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Every script is executed automatically on reload, even if it's cached, it gets executed. Whole approach seems wrong to me. Question also is confusing regarding click and load events.

Comment: It is just one of many attempts, I've tried with <body onload="loadAnnotator"> etc. Any other approach that works would be also fine.

Comment: Why not directly call that function. You are adding a listener then firing the click event.

Comment: Timing is the problem. Somehow, whatever I do I'm calling it too early. The DOM needs to be loaded. So I've tried with $(document).onready(loadAnnotator) but that is still not displaying my highlighted text. For example, this works:         <div id="pdfContainer" class = "pdf-content" onmouseover="loadAnnotator()">
        </div> but it's so obvious...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved**: I have added a timer and forced the button to be clicked after 300ms.

Somehow like this:

```
   <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="pdfContainer" class = "pdf-content">
        </div>
    </div>      
    <input id="btn" type="button" hidden="true" onclick="loadAnnotator()" />

    <script>

        var content = null;
        function loadAnnotator() {
            if (content === null) {
                content = $('#content').annotator();
            }
            console.log("Annotator loaded");
        }
        ;
        function clickedButton() {
            var btn = $("#btn")[0];
            if (btn !== null && btn !== undefined) {
                btn.click();
                console.log("Button is clicked");
            }
        }
        $(window).load(function () {
            setTimeout(clickedButton, 300);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Also, I've listened to suggestions as

```
var btn = $("#btn")[0];
```

Sometimes, one forgets about such fundamental things about jQuery :)
If I add time less then 300ms, it is behaving the way I mentioned above.

Thank you, all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the whole hack, try this oneliner instead:

```
$($('#content').annotator));
```

There's no need for the hidden button. If this doesn't work there's a chance 'annotator' isn't initialised until after this script.

Comment: Still - I change do content of my jsp, annotations are nicely display on reload, but when I reload again - no annotations (and annotator is reloaded)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `btn.click();` this doesn't work in some browsers!

JavaScript to rescue like this `btn[0].click();` or you need to change your logic as follows

```
  <body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="pdfContainer" class = "pdf-content">
    </div>
</div>      
<input id="btn" type="button" hidden="true" />

<script>

        var content =null;
    function loadAnnotator() { 
      if(content==null)content =$('#content').annotator();
        console.log("Annotator loaded");
    };
      function clickedButton(){
            loadAnnotator();
       }
    $(window).onLoad(function () {
        var btn = $("#btn");             
        if(btn !== null && btn !== undefined) {
            btn.on('click', clickedButton);     
            clickedButton();                   
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: No, this is working the same way...just loading the first the page is opened, and then, yes, annotator is loaded every time, but previously stored annotations are not being displayed...